# Laravel sending user notifications with specific setting values registered

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.8

I have been using tenancy concept long before and I was able to send tenant specific user notifications to users by using below Tenancy Provider. In short tenancy allow me to use same server with different databases in the same place.

For a new concept I wanted to add new fleets beneath each tenant and store their setting values using this strategy. Btw I'm using [anlutro/laravel-settings](https://github.com/anlutro/laravel-settings) for setting management.

This is how I store fleet related settings

```php
<?php
Setting::setExtraColumns(array(
    'fleet_id' => $relatedFleetId
));
?>
```

And this is how I receive fleet related settings from package

```php
<?php
Setting::setConstraint(function($query, $insert) use ($fleet_id) {
    if ($insert) {
      return;
    }

    $query->where('fleet_id', $fleet_id);
});
?>
```

So far I didn't have any problems related with setting values. Currently my problem is sending correct fleet notification to user. I have been using queue jobs for handling email and notifications on the project. For example with my current Tenancy Provider:

Notification scenario

- Tenant A - Fleet 1 -> Receive notification from Tenant A - Fleet 2 (I want this to be Tenant A - Fleet 1)
- Tenant A - Fleet 2 -> Receive notification from Tenant A - Fleet 1 (This one is ok)
- Tenant B - Nofleet -> Receive notification from Tenant B (This one is ok)
- Tenant C - Fleet 1 -> Receive notification from Tenant C - Fleet 3 (I want this to be Tenant C - Fleet 1)
- Tenant C - Fleet 2 -> Receive notification from Tenant C - Fleet 3 (I want this to be Tenant C - Fleet 2)
- Tenant C - Fleet 3 -> Receive notification from Tenant C - Fleet 3 (This one is ok)

What I'm thinking is registering on TenancyProvider is stuck with latest setting and can't change depending on fleet level but can change on tenant level. Here is the TenancyProvider (namespace and used classes are reduced with along unnecessary setting assignments)

```php
<?php

class TenancyProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $consoleDispatcher = false;

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureHttpRequests();
        $this->configureQueues();
        $this->configureConsole();
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }

    private function configureConsole()
    {
        if (! $this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            return;
        }

        // Add --tenant option to any artisan command.
        $this->app['events']->listen(ArtisanStarting::class, function ($event) {
            $definition = $event->artisan->getDefinition();
            $definition->addOption(
                new InputOption('--tenant', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The tenant subdomain the command should be run for. Use * or all for every tenant.')
            );
            $event->artisan->setDefinition($definition);
            $event->artisan->setDispatcher($this->getConsoleDispatcher());
        });

        // Check for tenant option on artisan command, setting environment if it exists.
        $this->getConsoleDispatcher()->addListener(ConsoleEvents::COMMAND, function (ConsoleCommandEvent $event) {
            $tenant = $event->getInput()->getParameterOption('--tenant', null);
            if (!is_null($tenant)) {
                $this->setEnvironmentForTenant($tenant);
            }
        });
    }

    protected function getConsoleDispatcher() : \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher
    {
        if (!$this->consoleDispatcher) {
            $this->consoleDispatcher = app(EventDispatcher::class);
        }
        return $this->consoleDispatcher;
    }


    private function configureHttpRequests()
    {
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            return;
        }

        $fleetId = null;
        if (request()->header('fleet_id')) {
            $fleetId = request()->header('fleet_id');
        } elseif (session()->has('fleet_id') && session('fleet_id') != 0) {
            $fleetId = strval(session('fleet_id'));
        }

        $this->setEnvironmentForTenant($this->getTenantSubdomainFromUrl(), $fleetId);
    }


    private function configureQueues()
    {
        // When a job is processed, check for tenant name to set correct environment.
        $this->app['events']->listen(\Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessing::class, function ($event) {
            if (isset($event->job->payload()['tenant'])) {
                $this->setEnvironmentForTenant($event->job->payload()['tenant'], $event->job->payload()['fleet_id']);
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Set the app environment for a given tenant.
     * DB, cache and aws settings are set here. Majority of app settings (name, mail, timezone)
     * are pulled from the db.
     *
     * @param string $tenant
     *
     * @throws UnknownTenantException
     */
    public function setEnvironmentForTenant(string $tenant, string $fleetId = null)
    {
        $connection = config('tenants.'.$tenant);
        if (! $connection) {
            if (env('RUNNING_IN_SINGLE_TENANT_MODE', false)) {
                return;
            }
            report(new UnknownTenantException('Unrecognised tenant: '.$tenant));

            // No prefix, not single tenant mode?
            // Why not show 403 page? It relies on a translator class which hasn't been booted yet.
            exit;
        }

        // Stamp the tenant name and fleet id on each queued job.
        Queue::createPayloadUsing(function () use ($tenant, $fleetId) {
            return [
                'tenant' => $tenant,
                'fleet_id' => $fleetId
            ];
        });

        app(Handler::class)->meta(['tenant' => $tenant, 'fleet_id' => $fleetId]);

        $this->setDatabaseConnection($connection);
        $this->setCacheSettings($tenant.'-'.$fleetId);

        $this->setMailSettings($fleetId);
        $this->setSocialSettings($fleetId);
    }

    public function getTenantSubdomainFromUrl() : string
    {
        return str_replace('.'.env('APP_PRIMARY_DOMAIN'), '', request()->getHttpHost());
    }

    /**
     * Force db connection to the tenant db.
     */
    private function setDatabaseConnection(string $connection)
    {
        config(['database.default' => 'tenants.'.$connection]);
        \DB::purge('mysql');
        \DB::reconnect('tenants.'.$connection);

        config(['settings.connection' => 'tenants.'.$connection]);
        // The settings singleton needs to be re-bound, as it has already latched on to the
        // original db connection.
        $this->app->singleton('anlutro\LaravelSettings\SettingsManager', function ($app) {
            /**
             * Construct the actual manager.
             */
            return new \anlutro\LaravelSettings\SettingsManager($app);
        });
    }

    private function setCacheSettings(string $prefix)
    {
        // Setting via config doesn't work at this point - go direct to facade for
        // request lifecycle.
        \Cache::setPrefix($prefix);
    }

    private function setMailSettings($fleetId)
    {
        app(SelectedSetting::class)->setFleet($fleetId);

        try {
            config(['mail.driver' => setting('mail_driver', 'smtp')]);
            config(['mail.host' => setting('mail_host', 'smtp.mailgun.org')]);
            config(['mail.port' => setting('mail_port', 587)]);
            config(['mail.encryption' => setting('mail_encryption', 'tls')]);
            config(['mail.username' => setting('mail_username')]);
            config(['mail.password' => setting('mail_password')]);
            config(['mail.from.address' => setting('mail_from_address')]);
            config(['mail.from.name' => setting('mail_from_name')]);

            config(['services.mailgun.domain' => setting('mailgun_domain')]);
            config(['services.mailgun.secret' => setting('mailgun_secret')]);

            (new MailServiceProvider($this->app))->register(); // register mail services again
            Mail::clearResolvedInstance('mailer'); // clear the facade instance to force resolving again
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            report($e);
        }
    }

    private function setSocialSettings($fleetId)
    {
        app(SelectedSetting::class)->setFleet($fleetId);

        try {
            config(['services.fcm.key' => setting('fcm_key', '')]);
            config(['services.fcm.key_terminal' => setting('fcm_key_terminal', '')]);

            (new NotificationServiceProvider($this->app))->register();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            report($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Also another side info. When I use `php artisan queue:listen` on my local all seems working fine like I wanted but when I switched to `php artisan queue:work` (My production is on work due to heavy load) this problem is happening. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance for reading out my question